# Haskell TypeSynonymInstances instance declaraton

Tags: haskell

I am getting the following error when trying to load the file using ghci> :l myfile.hs

```
• Illegal instance declaration for ‘ExpSYM String’

    (All instance types must be of the form (T t1 ... tn)

     where T is not a synonym.

     Use TypeSynonymInstances if you want to disable this.)

• In the instance declaration for ‘ExpSYM String’
```

in the line: instance ExpSYM String where

---

```
class ExpSYM repr where
    lit :: Int -> repr
    neg :: repr -> repr
    add :: repr -> repr -> repr
    
instance ExpSYM Int where
    lit n = n
    neg e = - e
    add e1 e2 = e1 + e2
    
eval :: Int -> Int
eval = id



instance ExpSYM String where
    lit n = show n
    neg e = "(−" ++ e ++ ")"
    add e1 e2 = "(" ++ e1 ++ " + " ++ e2 ++ ")"

view :: String -> String
view = id
```

---

I thought at first this was because of the double instance ExpSYM, but if I remove the first one (
instance ExpSYM Int) and it's eval I still see the error. How to fix? What is the issue?

Comment: Do as the error shows: add `TypeSynonymInstances` at the top of your file, that is, add `{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}` GHC's extension at the top of your file.

Comment: Thank you! I did see this as a way to resolve but the usage of the extension was not clear to me.

Comment: Then the [doc](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=typesynonyminstances#extension-TypeSynonymInstances) gives the full expalanation.

Comment: You'll almost certainly want `FlexibleInstances` if you want to solve the problem this way. But you might be better off using a `newtype` around `String`, or to `Text`.